# Use Function to replyTo RPC request

Tags: spring, kotlin, rabbitmq, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

I would like to use the `java.util.Function` approach to reply to an request send via `RabbitTemplate.convertSendAndReceive`. It's working fine with the `RabbitListener` but I can not get it working with the functional approach.

Client (working)

```kotlin
class Client(private val template RabbitTemplate) {

    fun send() = template.convertSendAndReceive(
        "rpc-exchange",
        "rpc-routing-key",
        "payload message"
    )

}
```

Server (approach 1, working)

```kotlin
class Server {

    @RabbitListener(queues = ["rpc-queue"])
    fun receiveRequest(message: String) = "Response Message"

    @Bean
    fun queue(): Queue {
        return Queue("rpc-queue")
    }

    @Bean
    fun exchange(): DirectExchange {
        return DirectExchange("rpc-exchange")
    }

    @Bean
    fun binding(exchange: DirectExchange, queue: Queue): Binding {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange).with("rpc-routing-key")
    }
    
}
```

Server (approach 2, not working) --> goal

```kotlin
class Server {

    @Bean
    fun receiveRequest(): Function<String, String> {
        return Function { value: String ->
            "Response Message"
        }
    }

}
```

With the config (approach 2)

```yaml
spring.cloud.function.definition: receiveRequest
spring.cloud.stream.binding.receiveRequest-in-0.destination: rpc-exchange
spring.cloud.stream.binding.receiveRequest-in-0.group: rpc-queue
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.receiveRequest-in-0.consumer.bindingRoutingKey: rpc-routing-key
```

With approach 2 the server receives. Unfortunately the response is lost. Does anybody know how to use the RPC pattern with the functional approach? I don't want to use the `RabbitListener`.

See [documentation/tutorial](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-spring-amqp.html).

Comment: Response is not lost, unless configured it is sent to `receiveRequest-out-0` exchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Cloud Stream is not really designed for RPC on the server side, so it won't handle this automatically like `@RabbitListener` does.

You can, however, achieve it by adding an output binding to route the reply to the default exchange and the `replyTo` header:

```
spring.cloud.function.definition: receiveRequest
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.receiveRequest-in-0.destination: rpc-exchange
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.receiveRequest-in-0.group: rpc-queue
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.receiveRequest-in-0.consumer.bindingRoutingKey: rpc-routing-key

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.receiveRequest-out-0.destination=
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.receiveRequest-out-0.producer.routing-key-expression=headers['amqp_replyTo']

#logging.level.org.springframework.amqp=debug
```

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So66586230Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So66586230Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    Function<String, String> receiveRequest() {
        return str -> {
            return str.toUpperCase();
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(RabbitTemplate template) {
        return args -> {
            System.out.println(new String((byte[]) template.convertSendAndReceive(
                    "rpc-exchange",
                    "rpc-routing-key",
                    "payload message")));
        };
    }

}
```

```
PAYLOAD MESSAGE
```

Note that the reply will come as a `byte[]`; you can use a custom message converter on the template to convert to String.

**EDIT**

In reply to the third comment below.

The `RabbitTemplate` uses [direct reply-to](https://www.rabbitmq.com/direct-reply-to.html) by default, so the reply address is not a real queue, it is a pseudo queue created by the binder and associated with a consumer in the template.

You can also configure the template to use temporary reply queues, but they are also routed to by the default exchange "".

You can, however, configure an external [reply container](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#reply-listener), with the template as the listener.

You can then route back using whatever exchange and routing key you want.

Putting it all together:

```
spring.cloud.function.definition: receiveRequest
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.receiveRequest-in-0.destination: rpc-exchange
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.receiveRequest-in-0.group: rpc-queue
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.receiveRequest-in-0.consumer.bindingRoutingKey: rpc-routing-key

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.receiveRequest-out-0.destination=reply-exchange
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.receiveRequest-out-0.producer.routing-key-expression='reply-routing-key'
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.receiveRequest-out-0.producer.declare-exchange=false

spring.rabbitmq.template.reply-timeout=10000

#logging.level.org.springframework.amqp=debug
```

```java
public class So66586230Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So66586230Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    Function<String, String> receiveRequest() {
        return str -> {
            return str.toUpperCase();
        };
    }

    @Bean
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer replyContainer(SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory,
            RabbitTemplate template) {

        template.setReplyAddress("reply-queue");
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = factory.createListenerContainer();
        container.setQueueNames("reply-queue");
        container.setMessageListener(template);
        return container;
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(RabbitTemplate template, SimpleMessageListenerContainer replyContainer) {
        return args -> {
            System.out.println(new String((byte[]) template.convertSendAndReceive(
                    "rpc-exchange",
                    "rpc-routing-key",
                    "payload message")));
        };
    }

}
```

IMPORTANT: if you have multiple instances of the client side, each needs its own reply queue.

In that case, the routing key must be the queue name and you should revert to the previous example to set the routing key expression (to get the queue name from the header).

Comment: Thanks alot :) As Spring Cloud Stream is not designed for RPC, do you think it's a good idea to use that in an production environment to achive transactional behavior using RabbitMQ?

Comment: It's fine to use it like that; it's just that you have to manually configure the output binding as I described; with that configuration, it works identically to how `@RabbitListener` works. We can do it because of the flexibility of RabbitMQ and spring-amqp and its binder; the same techniques might not work with all binders or, at least, may be more cumbersome to configure.

Comment: Is there any possibility to use a specific exchange instead of the default amqp.default one for the responses? We're using multiple virtual hosts and won't use the default one as a shared exchange. But the default exchange seems to have some special configuration which I can't reproduce.